# Kinect SDK installed, Camera Features do not work

Tags: kinect

I have the same problem with this post: [MSDN Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/db00f3ec-8641-45a5-ac5b-04b537963186). It seems nobody answered with a working solution on that thread.

### The symptoms:

- Kinect SDK 1.5 installed.
- The Kinect device is recognized and drivers seem to be loaded correctly.The speech demo works correctly.
- Skeleton Viewer shows "Could not enable Skeleton Tracking".
- Shape Game starts, but does not track anything.
- Kinect Explorer starts the small windows only showing that it has connected to the Kinect, the black window does not open. If I close the white window, the kinect explorer is still running I have to quit it through the task manager.
- When I unplug and plug the USB after I open Kinect explorer; it says insufficient bandwith.

### I tried:

- Updated BIOS.
- Updated motherboard software. (ASUS Maximus IV Gene-Z, Gen3)
- Removed all USB's and plugged them all.
- Restarted windows. (several million times)
- I uninstalled and re installed. Kinect SDK 1.0. (but everything is the same)

**My OS:** Windows 7 64 bit Ultimate.

I have been struggling with this for 1 complete day. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
EDIT: I tried my Kinect device on another computer (laptop), and it works.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally was able to made my kinect work. This [MSDN Discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/1edc452e-2f86-4426-97d5-2161ba932e69) helped me to do that.

### The solution:

1. Uninstall all Kinect Drivers from Control Panel.
2. Reinstall Kinect SDK.
3. **(IMPORTANT)** Make sure to skip getting drivers from windows update during driver installation.

And yay! It works beautifuly ..

Comment: I have a question. Did you check it for windows10 ?

Answer (score 3):

If the Kinect shares a USB Controller with other devices, a problem such as yours can happen easily.

Try the following: Unplug all USB devices, then connect *only* the Kinect to your computer. If you have USB mouse and/or keyboard, plug those into a different set of ports (for example front usb ports if you have the Kinect plugged into the back of the computer). Then, try running the SDK's sample applications.

Should this approach fail, something might be wrong with your USB controller(s).

One more option: Try running the sample applications on a different Windows computer, preferably a laptop of some type, since you won't need to plug in any additional USB devices.

If this approach fails, your Kinect is most likely defective. In which case you can get a replacement or refund from your retailer, if the purchase didn't happen too long ago.

Best of luck to you!

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention. I tried my Kinect on a laptop. And it works. I will try your suggested approach in a moment. Thanks for your answer. I will tell the results...

Comment: I closed my computer. Unplugged all USB's. Plugged only mouse/keyboard to front usb ports. Plugged my Kinect to the back of computer. Opened my computer. Opened samples. It still doesn't work.

Comment: The only remaining options I can think of are working on the laptop, or using a PCIe USB card for connecting the Kinect to your desktop computer. The latter approach is very unlikely to fail. Unfortunately, this is as far as my knowledge goes.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened with me; I noticed a windows update related to Kinect, installed it. Kinect stopped working. Installing SDK from May 2d 2012 didn't fix the problem. Rolling back to February 2010 SDK didn't fix it either. At first I guessed that Microsoft doesn't want us to use Kinect for Xbox any more, and this is their way of telling us to buy Kinect for Windows... well, may be - but in my case Kinect Camera driver was somehow updated to Version 1.5 (May 2, 2012), while everything else was on version 1.0. Installing original driver fixed the problem.

Comment: Sergei: I'm little confused. What did fix the problem? Can you provide a link or a specific SDK version number which worked for you?